# Find unique items of a list in Google Apps Script (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working with Google Sheets and I would like to get a list with the unique items of another list. Namely the input is:

List = ['Nick','George','George','Nick','Nick','George','Nick','Alex']

The output will be :

[Nick, George, Alex]

Right now I am using a simple loop to check whether an element appears more than once. But I am sure there is going to be a more clever way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is quite straightforward thanks to *ES6*. You need a combination of **filter()** and **indexOf()**.

Here is the solution:

```
var List = ['Nick','George','George','Nick','Nick','George','Nick','Alex']
  
const unique = (value,index,self) =>
{return self.indexOf(value) ===index;}
var Unique_List=List.filter(unique);
```

**Unique_List** will give you the desired result.

Output: `[Nick, George, Alex]`

> **References:**

- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way is to use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). This is defined as a collection that cannot have duplicates

```
var noduplicates = new Set(List);
```

You can convert this back to a list if you wish.

```js
var List = ['Nick', 'George', 'George', 'Nick', 'Nick', 'George', 'Nick', 'Alex']

var noduplicates = new Set(List)

noduplicates.forEach(x => console.log(x))
```

Comment: That is even neater than mine! thanks for posting that! Voteup!

Comment: I am not sure if that solution works in Google Apps Scripts though. For some reason new Set returns an empty object. I will check it again and let you know.

Comment: try iterating over it with forEach

Comment: The Logger of GAS shows an empty object when you ask it to display the Set. Using forEach returns the values though...
newSet.forEach( item => Logger.log(item) );

Comment: does not work...